# c# Forms - MVC frameworks?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I need to develop a forms application with a DB backend. In future this may be linked to ASP.NET page. I was thinking of doing this as an MVC and reuse later.

So, What kind of MVC frameworks do you use?

I am interested in building forms quickly and any frameworks that link/bind control to database fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no really famous MVC frameworks for Windows Forms.  There is probably a good reason for this - it's **really difficult to implement MVC with Windows Forms** due to the nature of the technology.  I think you're much better off using **MVVM** with Windows Forms and I'm saying this as a huge fan of MVC.

Otherwise you need to give us more details of what you're doing and then we could probably offer some better advice.

Answer (score 1):

[This O/R-Mapping-Framework](http://www.ffentityframework.net) includes a Solution for the MVC and Command-Pattern, which is recommended for Desktop-Applications.

There is a Demo-Application which demonstrates a simple Win-Forms-Application.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge there isn't a specific mvc framework for winforms, as for web applications (mvc2) . You'll have to implement the mvc (or better mv presenter) pattern by yourself. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MVC is really only a pattern to structure your code around.

If you are really going to take your app and port it to be available over the web later on then may I suggest that you code it as a WPF application using the MVVM pattern as this will involve less work in the long run.

Alternatively if use ASP from the start.